# Parse Cloud Code query doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm literally going crazy about this

```
var Questions = Parse.Object.extend('Questions');
var query = new Parse.Query(Questions);
console.log("hello1");
query.find({useMasterKey: true,
                  success: function(results) {
                       console.log("hello2");
                       response.success();
                  },
                       error: function(error) {
                       console.log("hello3");
                       response.error(error);
                  }
                  });
```

I just get in Parse Logs the "hello1" and nothing else. There should be code in the success case but I removed it to understand why this query doesn't even seem to be called. I even tried `query.find().then({.... });` but with no success. My table Questions is set as it should, it has several rows, why this query just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The find parameters shouldn't include useMasterKey.  Call it beforehand as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var Questions = Parse.Object.extend('Questions');
var query = new Parse.Query(Questions);
console.log("hello1");
query.find().then(function(results) {
    console.log("hello2, results = " + JSON.stringify(results));
    response.success();
}, function(error) {
    console.log("hello3, error = " + error.message);
    response.error(error);
});
```